# GoogleMaps api InfoWindow insert Html tags

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

How can I introduce `HTML` tags in a infowindow?  I know how to display text but i want to style it and to arrange it using paragraphs `<p>` and divs `<div>` .

Here is my function that displays the infowindow:

```
function getInfoWindowEvent(marker) {
    infowindow.close()
    infowindow.setContent("This is where my HTML content goes. But how?");
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
```

There should be something like `infowindow.setContent('<div>'+"some text"+'</div>')` but i don't know exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can add tags to the `infowindow.setContent()` so you've answered the question yourself.

```
function getInfoWindowEvent(marker) {
  infowindow.close()
  infowindow.setContent("<div>Some text</div>");
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
```

Comment: I just realized how to do it. Thanks anyway!